# What is the MYSQL query to check if returning array has more reference recursion in it?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, recursion

I have this table
myTABLE

```
  ID    |   ReferenceID
    ---------------------
    1   |   NULL
    2   |   NULL
    3   |   1
    4   |   1
    5   |   2
    6   |   2
    7   |   5
```

And I have a recursion function to display the results.

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM myTABLE WHERE ReferenceID =$1 ");
```

So this query will return

**ReturningArray = 3,4**

They stop there. No entry have them as a reference.

But

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM myTABLE WHERE ReferenceID =$2 ");
```

returns

**ReturningArray = 5,6**

and 5 has a further level.

So how can I check if the ReturningArray has more levels of reference or it just stops there?

Comment: Can you show the full recursive function?

Comment: So you want that the second example to return 5,6,7 since its ref_id equals the id = 5?

Comment: No. Just want a binary answer if 5,6 is being referenced in the future or not.

Answer (score 0):

If you want just one level of reference check, you can do it with the following SQL:

```
$dbLink = mysqli_connect(); //host, user, pass etc go here as arguments
$refId = 1; // your ReferenceID 
$refIdEscaped = mysqli_escape_string($refId); //always remember to escape input
$query = "SELECT main.*, 
   CASE WHEN ref.ReferenceID IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END as recursion_exists 
   FROM myTABLE main
   LEFT JOIN myTABLE ref ON main.ReferenceId = ref.ID
   WHERE main.ReferenceID = '{$refIdEscaped}'";
```

You'll get all data from your table with an additional column (`recursion_exists`) with values of 1 (if recursion exists) or 0 (if it does not exist).

For multiple recursions you can also do it with sql, adding more `LEFT JOIN`s like in the example above.

Comment: $query2 = mysql_query("SELECT main.*, CASE WHEN ref.popid IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END as recursion_exists FROM paints main LEFT JOIN paints ref ON main.popid = ref.id WHERE main.popid = {$id}");
 $tmprow=  mysql_fetch_array($query2);
 $recexist = $tmprow["recursion_exists"];
 if ($recexist==1){$classFloat="floatleft";}else{$classFloat="";}

Comment: Explain what "does not seem to work" mean, what are the errors/results. It would be much better if you posted your table on http://sqlfiddle.com/

Comment: Well, I disagree - **it does work :)**. Check out this fiddle (i added some rows from your question, tested the query and well) - it works:
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f69707/1/0

Comment: It does not. "WHERE main.popid = 2;" should returned 5 = 1 , 6= 0

Comment: With the data you provided (id:ReferenceID) like above (5:2),(6:2) it certainly works as expected. Modify the fiddle I posted with the data you actually have and explain the desired results and WHY you expect them.

Comment: 7 has a reference of 5 so that means that 5 keeps going on and so recursion occurs. So it should return 1 which is does. But not the same is happening with 6. 6 has no more references. It stops there. It should return 0 and not 1.

Comment: In the example you provided 6 has a reference of 2. All pairs (id, referenceId) look like this in the fiddle and your question: `(1,NULL), (2,NULL), (3,1), (4,1), (5,2), (6,2), (7,5)`. So I have no idea what you're looking at, but either it's something other than I'm looking at, or we must have a misunderstanding of a problem / db scheme etc.

Comment: I want to know if an entry(ID) has more references after it has been returned. 6 refers to 2 and has no more references. But 7 refers to 5 that is refering to 2. First is two level and third is three levels. I don't know if that makes sense. Maybe it's a bit complicated to answer.